# push notification to web-client from server in phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, push-notification

I have two different kinds of clients in my phonegap application. When a client request some data to server, the other client should be sent some data and notification. What is the best way to implement this? My application should run both on android and ios. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this. Maybe this helps
https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin
http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/
and if you want something with php then take a look at this
http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/sending-android-push